# Is using Castle Windsor singleton a valid approach for caching readonly data in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, castle-windsor

I have a .NET class that initialises some fixed readonly reference data. If I instantiate this class as a Singleton in Castle Windsor in ASP.NET then presumably all attempts to access this class by transient web calls will read from the single instance of the reference data in memory.

Is this a valid approach? Are there any downsides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely a valid approach.

Only downside as I see it is you need to make sure the class is re-entrant - it may be accessed by multiple threads concurrently.

Comment: Thanks! How do I make the the class re-entrant?

Comment: Thanks! How do I make the the class re-entrant? Presumably this just means safe to call one method before the previous calls has completely. If the call is reading from a Dictionary object, would this be OK?

Comment: You should guard the use of non-entrant data, like e.g. `Dictionary` which to my knowledge is NOT guaranteed to be re-entrant, by locks or stuff like that.

Comment: If you're on .NET 4, you can use the collections from the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace - e.g. `ConcurrentDictionary` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx )

Comment: What's the worst than can happen if I don't do any locking?

Comment: It's pretty hard to say anything general about that - it depends very much on what kind of logic you're doing, but I guess the worst thing that can happen - I mean, seriously, the WORST thing that can happen, is that everything seems to work when you develop your stuff, but you get weird unpredictable ill behavior when people are actually using the system

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET has a pretty effective caching framework (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx) which can do this for you, deal with expiry times, prioirtisation, can remove items from the cache when you're low on memory, etc.

As with everything, it depends on your use case - how much data you have, what form it takes, etc.